# Como entrenar LSTM con varias series temporales de diferente tamaño y multiples variables?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, redes-neuronales

Hola estoy intentando entrenar una LSTM con datos provenientes de mensajes de vuelos, los mensajes tienen los siguientes campos:
idVuelo = 2,Timestamp=Marcatemporal en s, altitud=xxx,latitud=xxxx,longitud=xxxx,velocidad=xxxx,aeropuertoOrigen=xxxx,Destino=xxxx,Aterrizaje=(marca temporal).

Cabe destacar que esto significa que hay diferentes idVuelo por tanto por cada idVuelo hay una serie temporal, los campos son los mismos para todas.El rango del timestamp es variable, con esto quiero decir que los mensajes se recogen cada 2,5,7,8,12 segundos depende de la antena entonces el timestamp no es fijo (ejemplo: todos los timestamp en rangos de 5s)

Lo que quiero hacer es usar todas las series para dada una serie sin acabar por ejemplo que le falten 15 min aprox de aterrizaje pueda predecir el campo Aterrizaje.

Por como funcionan las LSTM y dado mi problema creo que debería usar toda la serie en vez de x pasos atras para predecir la serie que le daría. Por ahora lo que he realizado es esto:

He cambiado todas las vairables a numericas, despues siguiendo un libro de LSTM aplicado a series temporales, recomiendan adaptar el dataset para que sea un problema de ML supervisado:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
# Form dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, previous=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-previous-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+previous), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + previous, 0])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)
```

He dividido el dataset en test y train

```
dftrain=df.loc[df["idVuelo"]<367]
dftest=df.loc[df['idVuelo']>368]
```

Se corresponde a un 70/30.

Aquí viene la parte peliaguda, a la hora de entrenar, lo que entiendo es que hay que entrenar cada serie de manera independiente y de forma incremental al modelo, y que para usar toda la serie lo que hago es que previous tenga la longitud de la serie-10 puntos. Todo esto son suposiciones y no se si lo estoy realizando de manera correcta.

```
 Nmodel = 0
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, input_shape=(1, previous)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
for name, group in dftrain.groupby('idVuelo'):
    seleccionX = group
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    train = scaler.fit_transform(seleccionX)
    #Select full time series with len-10
    previous = len(group)-10
    X_train, Y_train = create_dataset(train, previous)
    X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))

    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=128, verbose=2)
    modelosRestantes = modelosRestantes +1
    if((Nmodel%5) == 0):
        model.save(path)
        print("Model Saved: ", Nmodel)
    print("Ramaining series: ", Nmodel ,"de 367")
```

No se si esto me dará problemas posteriormente a la hora de realizar la predicción, porque no tengo muy claro si estoy prediciendo la variable aterrizaje, porque se supone que tendría que corresponderse al valor 'y' supongo, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida!

Muchas gracias!